# Extract E-mail from DB

Tags: mysql

In my db I have table: USERS

Structure: login, mail, coins

How extract e-mail only from users with has coins 0?

I try:

```
SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `coins` ........
```

where ..... need put something to extract but do not know what.

Comment: maybe this `coins = 0` ?

Comment: If the above comment does not help, you should post your database schema, too.

Comment: 'coins' is value , i need select users which have 0, but how?

Comment: Post table definition.

Comment: What fields your tables contain? Post ALL details. We can't use telepathy. :)

Comment: but I post all.. in db i have USERS, in this I have LOGIN, COINS, EMAIL

Comment: **Edit** your question with **all** relevant information, including your exact query, and the table definitions.

Comment: Yeah, baby, you did it! =) That was realy hard.

Comment: Yes, it is a very basic question. Yes the english is not crystal clear. But why vote down and close the question?

Comment: @RicardoAcras - in the original edit, the code was `SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'coins' 0`; it's clearly a typo, which are closed as "Too Localized"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE coins = 0;
```

Comment: I try with Newsletter tool and I have this error:  Error in Query: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 10' at line 1

Comment: this is workind in db but not in newsletter extract tool

Comment: Post your table structure and code you tried.

Comment: Table USERS, and structure LOGIN, MAIL, COINS

Comment: Remove ";" at the end of query and try to run it in your tool. Query: SELECT mail FROM users WHERE coins = 0

Comment: Show your code, what query you have written?